# ActionController::RoutingError is not handled on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I have a rails application with the following configs:

Heroku config:

```
RACK_ENV:                     production
RAILS_ENV:                    test
```

test.rb

```
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = true
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = false
```

production.rb

```
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true
```

application_controller.rb

```
  rescue_from Pundit::NotAuthorizedError do |exception|
    raise ActionController::RoutingError.new('Not Found')     
  end
```

In development environment, when I try to access an unauthorized page like /admin, the detailed "Routing Error" red page will come out, but when I pushed to heroku and try to access the same page again. the server would return 500 and the website would shows `An unhandled lowlevel error occurred. The application logs may have details:`Rack app error: #` I tried tuning the test and production environment rb but doesn't work. any thoughts?

Comment: Of course the red page wont appear on heroku. You should fix the error in development and the push to heroku with the error fixed.

Answer (score 0):

A Heroku production server set up with default settings will not show you the error messages on screen when they happen (you wouldn't want your users to see the details of what's going wrong, I guess).

You might want to install the heroku [rails12factor](https://github.com/heroku/rails_12factor) gem . This will make sure a little more information gets passed to your logs.

You can access these through

```
heroku logs
```

in the console to look at the logs or install one of the heroku logging add-ons for something a little more usable.